# Stability of zero-order hold controllers for linear systems

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes, linear-control

From what I've read, Lyapunov functions provide a very nice mechanism for verifying stability of continuous-time linear systems (non-linear as well, but that's not my concern at the moment). For example, for the system $x' = -x$, a Lyapunov function is $V(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$. It is easy to see that

1. $V(0) = 0$
2. $V(x) > 0$ for $x \neq 0$
3. $V(x)' = \frac{dV(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = -x^2 < 0$ for $x\neq 0$

which is sufficient to establish global asymptotic stability. However, what happens if I change this to a zero-order hold system with a non-constant sample period that is at most $\Delta$? In other words, at least every $\Delta$ time, $v$ is set to $-\frac{1}{\Delta}x$ and the system evolves according to $x' = v, v' = 0$. I think this system is still globally asymptotically stable. Is there a nice way to prove this, analogous to Lyapunov functions for continuous-time systems? Is there some way of saying that the zero-hold system is "close enough" to the continuous-time equivalent that the stability results still hold?

Comment: You need to define your zero order hold dynamics a little more clearly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, after $\Delta$ you will have $x(t) = 0$. So it is globally asymptotically stable in a trivial sense.

Comment: @copper.hat Good point. I meant for $v$ to be reset at least every $\Delta$ time. I edited the question to say this.

Comment: Zero order holds are not stable. But there are results for *sampled-data systems* which is the buzzword you need to google for.

Comment: @percusse I don't understand what you mean when you say that zero-order holds are not stable. Isn't the example in the question a zero-order hold that is globally asymptotically stable?

Comment: @BmoreDaniel That is not a zero-order hold model. Am I missing an obvious mistake ? It is a discrete time model of an autonomous system.

Comment: @percusse I probably did I poor job of explaining things. There are two examples in the question: one is continuous control and the other is a zero-order hold. The system evolves continuously according to $x' = v, v' = 0$, but at least every $\Delta$ time, the value of $v$ is set to $-\frac{1}{\Delta}x$ and held constant at that value until the next time it is set.